# Highchart - Datalabel overlaps across slices

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

How to disable data labels being overlapped across pie slices?

this is what i have in my chart options

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "overflow": false,
   distance: -30
}
```

Comment: a fiddle might give us more insight ..

Comment: Please recreate your chart as live demo on jsfiddle.net. This http://jsfiddle.net/ty10k5zg/ seems to not overlap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/samsonmathew/069hawjd/ . This has a clear example where the datalabels are placed within each slice and overlapping eachother. If the datalabels are spanning across other slices or couldnot be placed within that specific slice, Can we disable the specific datalabel? We need not show each and every datalabel as we have legends also

Answer (score 0):

There is no default logic for hiding overlapping `dataLabels` for pie type series with distance of `dataLabels` set as not positive number. You could define if `dataLabels` should be enabled on level of data point.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zxmpy84g/1/

Other way is to set up function that will hide or show `dataLabels` in `dataLabels`' `formatter`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zxmpy84g/